# Is the term "service city" correct for the main city served by an airport placed outside of that city?

Tags: airports, terminology

Some airports of big cities are, in fact, technically speaking in a "very near  municipality" which is not the main city itself.

For example the airport BCN serving "Barcelona" is, in fact, placed in the city "El Prat del Llobregat" which is 15 Km south from Barcelona.

Or for example the airport CDG serving "Paris" is, in fact, at the town "Roissy" 25 Km northeast from Paris.

I "think" (but can't confirm) I have heard the term "Service City" to refer to the "main city" the airport is conceptually associated to. For example to say "CDG's service city is Paris".

I'm trying to confirm this terminology with no luck.

Can anyone confirm, if this term is correct and provide any public source defining the term? If the term is not correct, what would be the correct one?

Comment: “catchment area” would be a related concept that seems more common.

Comment: What do you need the terms for ? The right choice of words often depends on the application and target audience.

Comment: "Service city" sounds weird to me. "Served city" or "City served" would probably be a bit more appropriate, though it does not quite feel very natural either. Maybe that could be more appropriate for https://english.stackexchange.com or https://ell.stackexchange.com?

Comment: As above, I wouldn't consider this question *off-topic*, but you might be more likely to get an answer elsewhere. For what it's worth: it's certainly not unusual to say that (for example) BCN "serves the city of Barcelona", but "service city" - or any similar noun phrase that I can think of - doesn't sound natural to me.

Comment: We have a site for [english.se] where you can ask about the user of specific words.

Comment: "Service city" sounds fine to me if you think of it as a city that mainly provides services to a nearby more important city. That's not to say I'm familiar with the term though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the point of view of a US pilot, it is generally termed as the “associated city“. But this term is only a general term used in publications like the [FAA UNITED STATES GOVERNMENT FLIGHT INFORMATION PUBLICATION CHART SUPPLEMENT](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/) legend. Every airport recognized by the FAA has an associated city. [Title 14, Code of Federal Regulations (CFR), Part 139 (14 CFR Part 139)](https://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/part139_cert/) also uses the term associated city. Even tiny and/or private airports have an associated city. In casual conversation, the term service, services, or servicing city would be just fine. Other governments may have different terminology in their documentation of airports.

Comment: I found multiple public links proving your answer. For example this excel https://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/part139_cert/media/part139-cert-status-table.xls mentioned in this faa.gov page https://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/part139_cert/?p1=definitions

Comment: Or for example those PDFs from Idaho https://www.idaho-airport-system-plan.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/IASP-Airport-Roles-Analysis-Chapter_FINAL.pdf or Nevada https://www.nevadadot.com/home/showdocument?id=3574 or this API documentation from Expedia https://developer.expediapartnersolutions.com/documentation/rapid-geography-docs-2-3/ - If you could please add them to your answer properly formatted I'd like to select it as "the answer", unless a more documentated option appears.

Comment: @XaviMontero - Thanks for the feedback. I was not sure if my answer would be suitable for your question. As I stated, I was looking at it from the perspective of a pilot. Keeping that in mind, I would be leery of including citations from outdated sources. The FAA and DOT are prone to change regulations over time. The FAA publishes new US Chart Supplements every 28 days. I am less familiar with each states DOT. They will vary state by state. As far as Expedia, I am not familiar with their Application Programming Interface at all. You can search any US chart Supp for the legend’s use of the term